# Disable button from going to next viewcontroller if textfields aren't filled

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having the issue with the textfields being empty and once I hit the button it continues to the next viewcontroller. I want to disable the button until all textfields are complete.

```
@IBAction func buttontapped(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
        let loginFunc = Login()
        loginFunc.login(First_Nm: First_Nm.text!, Pw: Pw.text!, Last_Name: Last_Name.text!, Email: Email.text!) { jsonString in
            let response = jsonString
            print(response)
            if response.range(of: "failure") == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHomeVC", sender: nil)
                }
        
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check for the `UITextField`s to see if the `text`'s `isEmpty` property is true before you proceed to `performSegue`.

```
@IBAction func buttontapped(_ sender: Any, forEvent event: UIEvent) {
    if First_Nm.text!.isEmpty || Last_Name.text!.isEmpty || Email.text!.isEmpty {
        print("Incomplete, show an alert for user's attention!")
        return
    }
    //...
}
```

Add-on: Also, follow a standard naming convention for your properties. Eg: Instead of `First_Nm` use `firstNameTextField`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve the disable and enable on the button based on textField input you can implement `UITextFieldDelegate` - `textFieldDidChange`

The code would look like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        
    firstNameTextField.delegate = self
    lastNameTextField.delegate = self
    passwordTextField.delegate = self
    emailTextField.delegate = self
}
```

And on the bottom of the ViewController file you can create extension for UITextFieldDelegate

```
extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidChangeSelection(_ textField: UITextField) {
        checkButtonState()
    }
    
    func checkButtonState() {
        var validFirstName = false
        var validLastName = false
        var validPassword = false
        var validEmail = false
        
        if firstNameTextField.text != "" {
            validFirstName = true
        }
        if lastNameTextField.text != "" {
            validLastName = true
        }
        if passwordTextField.text != "" {
            validPassword = true
        }
        if emailTextField.text != "" {
            validEmail = true
        }
        if validFirstName && validLastName && validPassword && validEmail {
            loginButton.isEnabled = true
        } else {
            loginButton.isEnabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

Then I would also recommend another check when the button is tapped similar to above answer however I think it could be a more extensive check on email and password. (Login might not be as important but during sign up you might want to validate password and email further than not empty)

You can make up your own rules but usually its something along the lines of

Validate password:
• Required 6-8 characters

```
if string.count < 6 {
    print("Password must be more than 6 characters")
}
```

• Maybe require one capital letter or one number

Validate email:
• Should contain "@"

```
if !string.contains("@") {
    print("probably not a valid email")
}
```

You can check the strings in the textfield to see if they meet the criteria if not return a login or sign up error to the user. Hopefully this gets you going in the right direction